# Istio RouteRule based on headers user-agent doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, istio

I have two services running on minikube, `Foo` and `Bar`. When I'm accessing the `Foo` service it makes a request to `Bar` service to retrieve some data. `Bar` service have 2 versions `"1.0"` and `"2.0"`.
I have setup the default `RouteRule` configuration with `istio` to route all the requests to `"1.0"`:

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RouteRule
metadata:
  name: bar-default
spec:
  destination:
    name: bar-server
  precedence: 1
  route:
  - labels:
      version: "1.0"
```

It works fine, and I can see that all the requests is forwarded to `"1.0"`.
Now I want to add another `RouteRule` based on the headers, so all the requests from `Chrome` browser will be forwarded to `"2.0"`:

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RouteRule
metadata:
  name: bar-v2
spec:
  destination:
    name: bar-server
  precedence: 2
  match:
    request:
      headers:
        user-agent:
          regex: ".*Chrome.*"
  route:
  - labels:
      version: "2.0"
```

And it doesn't work. All the requests are still routed to `"1.0"`.
I can see that the `RouteRule` is created:

```
> istioctl get routerules
NAME            KIND                    NAMESPACE
bar-default RouteRule.v1alpha2.config.istio.io  default
bar-v2      RouteRule.v1alpha2.config.istio.io  default
```

I can see in the developers tools in browser that the `UserAgent` header is present. 
How can I debug the request to see why doesn't it get forwarded to `"2.0"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that your Foo service does not pass the User-Agent header that it gets from the browser.

Additional check would be to perform a `curl` call to Bar from Foo by `kubectl exec` and to check that version 2.0 is called when passing it the User-Agent header:

`curl -H "user-agent: ---Chrome---" bar-server`

You can either install `curl` in your Foo container, or use a separate container with `curl`, like this one from [Istio samples](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/sleep/sleep.yaml)