# Istio VirtualService HTTP header match issue

Tags: istio

The following Istio 0.8 VirtualService fails to match the HTTP header.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: reviews
spec:
  hosts:
    - reviews
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        foo:
          exact: bar
    route:
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v2
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v3
```

I have followed https://github.com/istio/issues/issues/38 and [Istio RouteRule based on headers user-agent doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985038/istio-routerule-based-on-headers-user-agent-doesnt-work). However am unable to get it to function.

Pointers would be really helpful as the sleep service returns the product page similar to POSTMAN with no implication of the match condition!

Comment: Stumbled upon this thread https://github.com/istio/issues/issues/296 Looks like they have removed the functionality in 0.8

Answer (score 2):

This VirtualService by itself won't work if you don't have a `DestinationRule` to define your subsets (versions).

I will demonstrate how it should be done with the HelloWorld sample that is packed with the 0.8 release:

**Step 1:** Deploy the `samples/helloworld/helloworld.yaml`

**Step 2:** Define a `DestinationRule` for the two available versions:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: helloworld
spec:
  host: helloworld
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
```

**Step 3:** Replace the default `VirtualService` with the one that matches header attribute for routing:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: helloworld
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - helloworld-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        foo:
          exact: bar
    route:
    - destination:
        host: helloworld
        subset: v2
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: helloworld
        subset: v1
```

**Step 4:** Test it:

- Without header: `curl http://$INGRESS_GATEWAY/hello`

  Output:

  > Hello version: v1, instance: helloworld-v1-fd9b784bb-wcnj9
- With header: `curl -H "foo: bar" http://$INGRESS_GATEWAY/hello`

  Output:

  > Hello version: v2, instance: helloworld-v2-56694b7d6d-gbhqb

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the reviews service through the `ingressgateway`. If you aren't doing that, there are two ways you could be hitting a problem:

1. If you are calling productpage (`curl <ingress url>/productpage -H "foo: bar"`), there is not any logic to propagate the `foo: bar` header from productpage to the reviews service. The example with the `user-agent` works because the `user-agent` is automatically propagated (a special case). If you want to use `foo: bar`, you would have to add logic to the productpage service to grab the `foo` header and send it on to the reviews service.
2. You are calling the reviews service directly (for instance, you gave the reviews service a node port). This would fail because your request is not being routed by an Istio proxy --instead it is being handled by the k8s service load balancer. You need to call an Istio proxy, like the `ingressgateway`.